# Shapefile with different NAD83 zones

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, nad83

I have a shapefile with zone 17 and 18 as content, and zone 18 as coordinate system. When using coordinates of zone 17 there is an error.

What to do?

Comment: You have an invalid shapefile, with two UTM  datasets in a single file.  Your only option is to create two correct shapefiles with one spatial reference each.  Note that NAD83 doesn't  have zones (it's a geographic coordinate system), but "UTM nnd (NAD83)" does have zones.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! It looks like you have a coordinate system problem, see if any of the suggestions at https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/ help.